# how to open specific browser in UWP?

Tags: browser, uwp

```
var uriBing = new Uri(@"chrome://www.bing.com");
var success = Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uriBing);
```

how can I open a specific browser in UWP app?
for example, if user want to open "gmail.com", open tab in chrome. if user want to open dev.windows.com, open tab in edge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LaunchUriAsync` method has a [LauncherOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.System.LauncherOptions#Windows_System_LauncherOptions_TargetApplicationPackageFamilyName) parameter, you could specify the `TargetApplicationPackageFamilyName` for it. For example, the Edge is "Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe".

```
Uri uri_windows = new Uri("https://developer.microsoft.com/");
var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
options.TargetApplicationPackageFamilyName = "Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe";
var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri_windows, options);
```

But for [Google browser](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/google/9wzdncrfj2gk), I can find its TargetApplicationPackageFamilyName is "GoogleInc.GoogleSearch_yfg5n0ztvskxp". But the following code didn't work. I didn't know why.

```
Uri uri_mail = new Uri("https://mail.google.com");
var _options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
_options.TargetApplicationPackageFamilyName = "GoogleInc.GoogleSearch_yfg5n0ztvskxp";
success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri_mail, _options);
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer! Maybe google doesn't like MS. In addition, How can i find TargetApplicationPackageFamilyName?

Comment: GoogleInc.GoogleSearch_yfg5n0ztvskxp is not chrome but an App Store app related to google's MS store app.. Only way to get this to work for chrome would be to make [chrome] default application for browsing.